# feign.Client metric is not capturing ResponseCode

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-cloud-feign, feign, spring-micrometer

i want to capture responseCode metric using feign client. i am able to capture metrics using feign Client but it is capturing only method,host and client metric. i.e

```
# TYPE feign_Feign_seconds_max gauge
feign_Feign_seconds_max{client="com.example.account.api.AccountApiClient",host="localhost",method="getByAddress",} 0.0
```

i want to capture Response Code as well.

We do have option in Rest Templete by using RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider. but i dont find any similar option for Feign.